# Function is not working on radio button onclick

Tags: javascript, forms

JavaScript function (here `f1()`) is not getting called on radio button (here id=`iprange`) `onclick` event.

HTML

```js
function f1() {
    alert('yes');
}
```

```html
<form role="form">
    <div class="box-body">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="fullscan1" value="option1" /> Full Scan
        </label>

        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


<!-- "IP Range" is the radio button that should show a "yes" alert. -->
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="iprange" value="option2" onclick="f1();" /> IP Range

        </label>
        From:
        <input type="text" id="text1"> To:
        <input type="text" id="text2"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="subnet" value="option3" /> Subnet

        </label>
        <input type="text" id="text3"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


        <button class="btn btn-danger">Scan</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Try `onfocus`, should work.

Comment: I think onfocus will not work on all browsers. will it?

Comment: Set your function in `script`-tags into `head` and try again.

Comment: This works for me http://jsfiddle.net/w75577pp/

Comment: adding script to head or document on ready will work http://jsfiddle.net/2q52y3n5/

Comment: @Sumeet On `document ready` **does not** work.

Comment: I have tried adding script to head. It is not working in my html page.
If I change my button type from radio to button, it's working as expected.

Comment: Are you running some other code that does something with your button ?

Comment: @MartinErnst, No I m not running any other code. But above html code is a part of my html page

Comment: Sorry, my last question wasn't clear enough. Are there some more `<script>` in your html ?

Comment: yes, I have one more script tag on document ready

Comment: @Suresh Kota I have edited answer, please try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Suresh Kota . At this point its impossible to give an satisfying answer, you'll have to do a step-by-step-investigation. Start with following and post your result here.

```
<head>
    ....
    <script> // your script tag, I assume it looks like this
        $(document).ready(function() {
            /* some code */
        });
        // now include your function as last line outside document ready
        function f1() {alert('yes');};
    </script>
    <!-- Make sure this is the only script tag in your html -->
    ....
</head>
```

If that doesn't help, rename your function, e.g. `function xxx() {alert('yes');};`

and same with onclick-attribute in input-tag: `onclick="xxx()"`.

When having no succes, try directly: `onclick="alert('yes')"`

If that all not work, there's something inside your document.ready that manipulates the button, and you should post that code.

Comment: Got it. Yes, I have some js code which is manipulating the radio button. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" onclick="handleClick(this);" value="option1" />
<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" onclick="handleClick(this);" value="option2" />
...

<script>
function handleClick(myRadio) {
    alert('New value: ' + myRadio.value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can always use pure javascript for this one, thats an alternative, and totally separates your html from js.

Answer (score 0):

`<label onclick="red()"><input type="radio" name="colors" id="red">Red</label>`

or
 
`<label onclick="red()"><input type="radio" name="colors" id="red"></label>
<label for="red">Red</label>`

```
<script>
function red(){
 alert('i am red');
}
</script>
```

if you want to call onclick function on radio button then you can use like this, it will work for you

Note: we have to call on function on label instead of radio button